# Regex - match first word before hyphen and digit and file extension

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to write a regex expression that will capture the first word up until a hyphen, and then **ALSO** match a digit and file extension.

Here is an example string:
`lorem-ipsum-dolor-15.jpg`

I know that `[\d]+(.jpg)` will match `15.jpg`

I also know that `^[^-]*[^ -]` will match the first word up until the hyphen, in this case `lorem` but it won't match anything beyond that.

How can I reconcile these 2 expressions into one? I'll also settle for a reverse match of what I'm asking for.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a language tag. Regular expressions come in many flavors.

Comment: You can do `'lorem-ipsum-dolor-15.jpg' -match '(^[^-]+).*?(\d+\.[^$]+)'`

Comment: For only capturing `lorem` try e.g. [`^([^ -]*)\S*-\d+\.jpg`](https://regex101.com/r/KkMLJX/1) but if you want to capture `lorem-ipsum-dolor` use e.g. [`^(\S+)-\d+\.jpg`](https://regex101.com/r/KkMLJX/2) (Sidenote: Escape the `.` from its special regex-meaning to match a literal dot).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is JS, you should be able to just join the two patterns with `.*?` (that is, match any character, any number of times, in a non-greedy fashion).

So something like:

```
/^([^-]*[^ -]).*?(\d+\.jpg)$/
```

The first capture group will be the leading `lorem`, and the second will be `15.jpg`.

Check out [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wPvnJU/1) for more detail.